# Android avoid closing Toast when click on it

Tags: android, android-toast

This is how i show my Toast message.

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is my Toast message!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

When i click on Toast it will disappear. 
How can I avoid sudden disappear of Toast when i click on it.

Comment: Toast.LENGTH_LONG is your time length change it to reflect your need. it automatically gets disappear after time interval.

Comment: No. When i set LENGTH_LONG it will stay for few seconds. But when i click on the Toast it will close without staying for few seconds. I want to keep Toast for few seconds without disappearing though i click on it.

Comment: Well then, you have to create your own Toast and handle the behaviour there.
Visit here to create one:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 2):

Toast doesn't disappear for sudden clicks . , it will disappear on with duration u set

Comment: No. When i set LENGTH_LONG it will stay for few seconds. But when i click on the Toast it will close without staying for few seconds. I want to keep Toast for few seconds without disappearing though i click on it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html).

Snackbar has `LENGTH_INDEFINITE` attribute on the duration so I think it is pretty much what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Toasts doesn't close on interactions it depends on the duration you set which are

LENGTH_SHORT and LENGTH_LONG are 0 and 1.  If you want something that stays longer use actionbar notifications

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: No. When i set LENGTH_LONG it will stay for few seconds. But when i click on the Toast it will close without staying for few seconds. I want to keep Toast for few seconds without disappearing though i click on it.

Comment: @thinuwan  a toast cannot be clicked theres no specific view behind it and if you check on the api for toasts theres no Click function defined for it

Answer (score 0):

Andorid Toast can be used to display information for the short period of time. A toast contains message to be displayed quickly and disappears after sometime.

You can also create custom toast as well

```
//Creating the LayoutInflater instance  
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();  
        //Getting the View object as defined in the customtoast.xml file  
            View layout = li.inflate(R.layout.customtoast,  
              (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));  

        //Creating the Toast object   
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());  
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);  
            toast.setView(layout);//setting the view of custom toast layout  
            toast.show();  

OR ..

Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello Javatpoint",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
toast.setMargin(50,50);  
toast.show();
```

You can use the for loops for duration

Comment: No. When i set LENGTH_LONG it will stay for few seconds. But when i click on the Toast it will close without staying for few seconds. I want to keep Toast for few seconds without disappearing though i click on it.